# Tomcat in Azure WebApp does not start

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created a webapp in Azure and uploaded a war file in D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps folder. I use an app service plan with a standard pricing tier.
I've done the settings to activate Java and Tomcat in Application Settings menu:

- java version : Java 8
- java minor version : Newest
- Web Container: Newest Tomcat

If the option "Always On" is not activated, my Tomcat does not start. No java process is started, my war file is not unzipped. I've done several stop/start of the app and nothing happens.
Once I've activated the "Always On", the Tomcat starts and the app is deployed.
The "Always On" is not available on Service Plan with a Free pricing tier.

Does anybody know why Azure behaves that way ?

Comment: does it start/unzip after your first request to the service, or does it "never" start?

Comment: it never starts. When I deactivate the "Always On" option, the java process is killed.

Comment: sounds like an Azure support call, or MSDN forums.  This doesn't seem like normal behavior IMHO

Comment: As @CtrlDot said above the behavior i have observed is when "Always On" is not activated the activity (start/unzip) happens on the first request. After some inactive time again app is undeployed and tomcat is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the behavior as you said via FTP, here is what I observed on Tomcat 8.5.6 as @GopiKolla said, as below .

1. If disabled `Always on` option, the `.war` file uploaded will not be unpacked automatically. However, when I tried to access the url of the webapp of the `.war` file, it was unpacked to a directory which named as same as war after ten more seconds.
2. If enabled this option, all war file will be unpacked automatically & immdiately.

I had check all configurations & environment variables which include the attributes `autodeploy`, `unpackWARs` & `deployOnStartup`, etc, these would not change with the option switch. I searched the explaination for this case from the offical related documents of Tomcat ([1](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/deployer-howto.html), [2](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) ,[3](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F)), there is nothing useful information which can explain it. Just a guess & per my experience, I think Azure limits the lifecycle of runtime via IIS to determine whether activate the `httpPlatformHandler` process defined in the `web.config` via the option `Always on`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your feedback.
I did the test again yesterday and I think I've understood how Azure WebApp works. 
When you upload a war file in webapps folder, even if the tomcat is configured to unpack and load the war, the java process is not started.

**It will start the java process only if you click on the URL of your website.**

If you don't click, no java process is forked. The first click will fork the java process for Tomcat.

I suppose it's the normal behaviour of the IIS worker.

So now, when I deploy a Java app, I always perform a touch on the URL to make sure the webapp is really started.